# A question about roots for a quartic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let  $k\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=x^{4}+(2-k^{2})x^{2}-2k^{2}x+(1-k^{2})$. Suppose that there are exactly two distinct real roots for the equation $f(x)=0$. Find the range of $k$.

I don't know the conditions that $f(x)=0$ has exactly  two distinct real roots.

Comment: Hint: express this polynomial to a difference of two polynomial squares.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=x^{4}+(2-k^{2})x^{2}-2k^{2}x+(1-k^{2})$$
$$f(x) = x^4+2x^2+1-k^2(x^2+2x+1)$$
$$f(x)=(x^2+1)^2 -k^2(x+1)^2$$
$$f(x)=(x^2+1)^2 -(k(x+1))^2$$
$$f(x)=((x^2+1)-k(x+1))((x^2+1)+k(x+1))$$
$$f(x)=(x^2+1-kx-k)(x^2+1+kx+k)$$

SO you have two polynomials
$$x^2+1-kx-k\tag1$$
$$x^2+1+kx+k\tag2$$

Now Solving for x
\begin{cases}
- \frac{1}{2} k - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{k^{2} - 4 k -4}\\
- \frac{1}{2} k + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{k^{2} - 4 k -4}\\
\frac{1}{2} k - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{k^{2} + 4 k -4}\\
\frac{1}{2} k + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{k^{2} + 4 k -4}\\
\end{cases}

Now solve the inequality

\begin{cases}
k^{2} - 4 k -4 \ge 0\\
k^{2} - 4 k -4 \ge 0\\
k^{2} + 4 k -4 \ge 0\\
k^{2} + 4 k -4 \ge 0\\
\end{cases}